# How do you cross the Schelde (Scheldt) in Flanders by bike during the tunnel works in Antwerp?

Tags: belgium, antwerp

In a few months, the Voetgangerstunnel/Sint-Annatunnel (Pedestrian tunnel) from Linkeroever to Antwerp will close due to works on the elevators. It is the only safe way to travel to Antwerp by bike. Now, I was wondering if there will be a (free) alternative to that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a [free ferry for pedestrians and cyclists](http://www.portofantwerp.com/nl/news/vanaf-1-juli-verbindt-gratis-veerdienst-%E2%80%98sint-anna%E2%80%99-linker-en-rechteroever-antwerpen) (link to Dutch page, couldn't find an English version) that connects both sides of the river as an alternative to the tunnel.

The schedule is rather limited: between 7:30 and 18:30 during the week and until 21:30 during the weekend. Outside those times it looks like you will have to go all the way to the Kennedy Tunnel. It only started a few days ago, so probably that might change a bit depending on the demand.

The location is shown in [Openstreetmap](http://www.openstreetmap.org/#map=17/51.22329/4.39670).

Answer (score 3):

More to the south of Antwerp, there is another tunnel for cyclists next to the Kennedytunnel. Going to Antwerp, you can access it on the left bank of the Scheldt river on the [Beatrijslaan](https://www.google.be/maps/@51.2088427,4.3701724,3a,43.5y,300.23h,84.26t/data=!3m6!1e1!3m4!1s28g0E2BqJltMSU6emDi42Q!2e0!7i13312!8i6656).
If you leave Antwerp, you will find the tunnel at the right bank of the river at the [D'Herbouvillekaai](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Fietserstunnel/@51.2033083,4.3718525,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x47c3f6986f8e219f:0xba32e18b872927a9!8m2!3d51.2033083!4d4.3740412)

EDIT : I see that you can watch the status of the elevators in both tunnels and the ferry on [this webpage](http://fietsersliften.wegenenverkeer.be/) (only in Dutch unfortunately)